# Row-like string with even spacing in between values

Tags: c#, layout, listbox

I'm trying to add multiple lines and with different sections to a ListBox, and am required to use "\t" for creating a layout.

```
listBox.Items.Add(emp[index].first + "\t\t" + emp[index].last + "\t\t" + emp[index].number + "\t\t" + emp[index].department + "\t\t" + "Annual Salary: " + (emp[index].annualSalary).ToString("c") + ", Annual Bonus: " + (emp[index].annualBonus).ToString("c"));
```

Just one example line.

It comes out looking like: (without the dots)

> Mary.......Sue................778-435-2321.....Accounting.....Annual Salary: $33,000.00
>   Trevor....Joseph...........604-894-2902.....Marketing.......Annual Salary: $52,000.00
>   Steve......Collin.............778-234-5432.....Finance..........Annual Salary: $48,500.00
>   George...........Watson..........604-910-2349.....Technical.......Annual Salary: $25,000.00
>   Sally.......Henderson.....604-654-2325.....Sales..............Annual Salary: $12,000.00
>   Jenny.....Motgomery.....604-692-4932.....Data Ana.......Annual Salary: $12,000.00

Can anyone explain why it's displaying all wonky, and how I might fix this?
I've searched online, but couldn't find any results using \t for layout.

Comment: George is a big man.  You can never get this perfectly right, there is no point in avoiding a ListView with View = Details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I highly suggest using a pattern instead of concatenating your strings using plus sign. This will help you see things more clear:

```
string pattern = string.Format("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\tAnnualSalary: {4}, Annual Bonus: {5}", 
emp[index].first, 
emp[index].last, 
emp[index].number,
emp[index].department, 
emp[index].annualSalary).ToString("c"),
emp[index].annualBonus);
```

The answer to your question is that you are using tabs assuming they will fill the space for you, but they won't. You need to use advanced features of

> string.Format or  string.Pad

Full answer can be found here: [Formatting a C# string with identical spacing in between values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784032/formatting-a-c-sharp-string-with-identical-spacing-in-between-values)