# c# Tab a string the right way

Tags: c#, string

so...

I am creating a program, and at some point it writes:

```
sitename.com : 1
longersitename : 1
short.com : 1
```

and I want to write it like:

```
sitename.com   : 1
longersitename : 1
short.com      : 1
```

I tried adding \t, the problem is it will then make somethin like:

```
sitename.com      : 1
longersitename      : 1
short.com      : 1
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Edit: Everyting is in the same string, code:

```
Console.WriteLine(allResults.Groups[1].Value.Replace("has: ", " : ").TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).TrimStart(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()));
```

The **" : "** part is the part that needs to tab.

Edit: this is the string: (this is 1 string, with \n\r)

```
Unknown Site : 1  URL found.
Google Search : 3  URL found.
Youtube : 5  URL found.
Core  : 1  URL found.
Console : 88  URL found.
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Find longest string and use [`string.PadRight()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx) (to pad with spaces).

Comment: @juharr I can not really use spaces, because I don't know which sitenames are going to write (I get the list from an API, based on a search).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784032/formatting-a-c-sharp-string-with-identical-spacing-in-between-values

Comment: @Sinatr I editted my question, my code is in 1 string.

Comment: Could you provide, please, the initial *one string*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Editted the question with the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq* as well as *regular expressions* to obtain values:

1. *Split* By *new line*
2. *Split* by ':', in order to get rid of `URL found.` and obtain the number, use *regular expression*
3. *Format* out name and value into single line, specify *lengths* and *alignments*
4. Finally, *combine* all the lines back into a single string.

Implementation:

```
  String source = 
    "Unknown Site : 1  URL found.\r\n"+
    "Google Search : 3  URL found.\r\n" +
    "Youtube: 5  URL found.\r\n" +
    "Core: 1  URL found.\r\n" +
    "Console: 88  URL found.";

  //TODO: put actual lengths (instead of 15 and 3) in the formatting
  var target = source
    .Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
    .Select(items => String.Format("{0,-15}: {1,3}", 
       items[0].Trim(), 
       Regex.Match(items[1], "[0-9]+").Value));

  String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, target);

  ...

  // Unknown Site   :   1
  // Google Search  :   3
  // Youtube        :   5
  // Core           :   1
  // Console        :  88
  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: @Matthew Dotcom: you're welcome! Next time, please, start with *initials* :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `monospaced` font printing the string. 
The best way to align strings is using [`String.Format` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will have to determine the longest site's name for this.

Comment: I just edditted my question, everyting is in one string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample that takes some key/value pairs and formats them with the sort of spacing you're describing:

```
var valuesOfVaryingLengths = "key: value, longer key: value, even much longer key: value";
var pairs = valuesOfVaryingLengths.Split(',')
    .Where(pair => pair.Contains(":")).ToArray()
    .Select(pair => pair.Split(':')).ToList();
var longest = pairs
    .Select(pair => pair[0]).Max(key => key.Length);
var padded = pairs.Select(
    pair => string.Concat(pair[0].Trim().PadRight(longest), ": ", pair[1].Trim()));
padded.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```