# C# - Convert to string with format?

Tags: c#, string, format, padding

The goal, is to transmit an message with some chars, and some values to another system, that will read the value, but I need to format the values for the other system to be able to read it.

Right now I have some code:

```
string Message = Convert.ToString({"x=" + x1 + "y=" + y1 + "idle=" + idle1 + "RT=" + RT + "LT=" + LT} );
```

Which works to some degree, the `x=x1` work, such that the value will look like `x=1` or `x=65534` 
but the system that receives the message needs to read the string, and I would do it by reading it like an array, but that means that the values needs to have fixed sizes, so I would need to format `x=1` to `x=00001` instead.

I have seen some do it with "D6" as an parameter, but I cant get it to work with Convert to string.

Comment: Search for string.Format("x={0:D6}......", x1, .....); Here: [Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427194/formatting-a-string-into-columns-using-string-interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.PadLeft(5, '0') to always get 5 Chars

```
public string FormatVal(int value)
{
  return value.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
}
```

and then

```
string Message = $"x = {FormatVal(x1)} y = {FormatVal(y1)}idle = {FormatVal(idle1)}RT = {FormatVal(RT)}LT = {FormatVal(LT)}";
```