# What does mean {0,8:c} in c#?

Tags: c#

I read this code in MS document.
What does 8 before 'c' mean?

```
Console.WriteLine("Bill total:\t{0,8:c}", billTotal);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427387/2946329

Comment: `{0,8:c}` decrypted: `0` - *index* (0th item will be taken - `billTotal`), `8` -  minimum *size* (at least `8` characters, right alignment, since `8` is *positive*); `c` - *format string* (currency format)

Comment: Thank you. I spend a lot of time because of this question.