# formating the buffer input from ReadExisting() on c#

Tags: c#, formatting

i have a program where i read a list of values from an energy meter through a serial port.
to read the buffer i use the ReadExisting() method.
my problem is that the words in the second column have different length each raw so the list is not orginized well:

[image]

i am looking for a way to make it look like this:
[image]

Thanks,

Shay.

i have tried the suggestions from the answers, but could not reach the right format.
here is the code i use:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Showdata));
        }

       
        private void Showdata(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                textBox1.Text += DataIn;
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.TextLength;
                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
         }
```

how can i get the input from the buffer to be aligned?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting a string into columns using String Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427194/formatting-a-string-into-columns-using-string-interpolation)

Comment: Thank you,  i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tab. Like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"value: \t{...} \t{...}");
```

\t is a tabulator where it gives you the actual tab

or...

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}{4,10}",
  a[DisplayPos],
  b[DisplayPos],
  c[DisplayPos], 
  d,
  e);
```

where the first number inside the curly brackets is the index and the second is the alignment. The sign of the second number indicates if the string should be left or right aligned. Use negative numbers for left alignment.

Or look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @ShayAvitapl  Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you